# "Unknown column" with JPA on AS400 db2

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm receiving the following error:

> could not execute query; SQL [select      DFBOGARM,     sum(KVANTUM1)
>   as KVANTUM1,     (sum(DSTOMK) * 1000 / sum(KVANTUM1)) as DSTOMK,
>     (sum(DSTAKK) * 1000 / sum(KVANTUMAKK)) as DSTAKK from
>   NHODATA.ERHDSTV1 where DFSALVAR in(52, 55) group by DFBOGARM order by
>   DFBOGARM]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not
>   execute query
>
> Caused by: com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCSQLSyntaxErrorException: An
>   undefined column name was detected.

Query implementation:

```
public interface DistributionRepository extends JpaRepository<ERHDSTV1, Long> {

@Query(value="select  "
        + "    DFBOGARM, "
        + "    sum(KVANTUM1) as KVANTUM1, "
        + "    (sum(DSTOMK) * 1000 / sum(KVANTUM1)) as DSTOMK, "
        + " (sum(DSTAKK) * 1000 / sum(KVANTUMAKK)) as DSTAKK "
        + "from NHODATA.ERHDSTV1 "
        + "where DFSALVAR in(52, 55) "
        + "group by DFBOGARM "
        + "order by DFBOGARM", nativeQuery = true)
List<ERHDSTV1> findSummedValuesFor52and55();}
```

Entity class :

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ERHDSTV1Id.class)
@Table(name = "ERHDSTV1")
@Data
public class ERHDSTV1 {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "DFBOGARM")
   private String yearMonth;
   @Id
   @Column(name = "DFSALVAR")
   private Long salesType;
   @Column(name = "KVANTUM1")
   private Long volumeOne;
   @Column(name = "DSTOMK")
   private Long distributionCosts;
   @Column(name = "DSTMDN")
   private Long distributionMedian;
   @Column(name = "KVANTUMAKK")
   private Long volumeAccumulated;
   @Column(name = "DSTAKK")
   private Long distributionAccumulated;
   @Column(name = "DSTMNDAKK")
   private Long distributionMedianAccumulated;
}
```

The query from error message executes perfectly, when executed from an sql tool.

and headers are: DFBOGARM, KVANTUM1, DSTOMK, DSTAKK

Comment: Does your DBMS expects your column names in lower case? Does the message specifies which column name is allegedly undefined? Can you let your app print out the actually generated SQL?

Comment: Updated, but, no, no specific column is mentioned, also, it should not matter if it's upper or lower case.

Comment: seems that the error indicates that the SQL query is wrong, have you tried running it directly against your DB?

Comment: "The query from error message executes perfectly, when executed from an sql tool"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so the error was that I have to select values for every column above.

which means i made the query like this:

```
@Query(value = "select  "
        + "    DFBOGARM, 1 as DFSALVAR, 1 as DSTMND, 1 as DSTMNDAKK, 1 as KVANTUMAKK, "
        + "    sum(KVANTUM1) as KVANTUM1, "
        + "    (sum(DSTOMK) * 1000 / sum(KVANTUM1)) as DSTOMK, "
        + " (sum(DSTAKK) * 1000 / sum(KVANTUMAKK)) as DSTAKK "
        + "from NHODATA.ERHDSTV1 "
        + "where DFSALVAR in(52, 55) "
        + "group by DFBOGARM "
        + "order by DFBOGARM", nativeQuery = true)
```

and that worked.

Comment: I had similar problem with column upper-case names.  This answer aided in resolving the issue.